# Что такое Доменный объект и Предметная область, простым языком?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, терминология

Начал изучать ООП и часто встречаю упоминание о *Доменный объект* и *Предметная область*. Особенно часто вижу их в контексте *Репозитория*. Поскольку к полному погружению в книги Эванса и Вернона еще не готов.  Было прочитано множество статей и выборочно главы из данных книг. К сожалению, не совсем понял,  даже поверхностно, что они из себя представляют. Я опишу как понимаю данные понятия, Вас попрошу исправить меня или дополнить.

**Предметная область** - представляет часть реального мира, которая должна быть реализована в нашей системе.
Пример:

1. Блог - создание и публикация
2. Отдел кадров - учет сотрудников
3. Аукцион - продажа товаров

**Доменный объект** - представляет собой основные значимые сущности, которые относятся к предметной области. Класс, который описывает основные аттрибуты и возможное поведение.

1. Блог:

   - Запись/Пост
   - Читатель/Пользователь
   - Комментарий
2. Отдел кадров:

   - Сотрудник
   - Подразделение
3. Аукцион:

   - Товар
   - Покупатель/Пользователь

Доменный объект, который не содержит в себе ничего кроме аттрибутов, геттеров и сеттеров - называется *Без кровным* (Anemic) и является антипаттерном.

```
class Account
{
    private Id $id;
    private Balance $balance;
    private Status $status;
    private array $clients;
}
```

Доменный объект должен содержать всю бизнес-логику для работы с данным объектом.

```
class Account
{
    private Id $id;
    private Balance $balance;
    private Status $status;
    private array $clients;


    public function addClient(int $id);
    public function removeClient(int $id);
    public function rechargeBalance(int $amount);
}
```

Так же интересует, что означает "Уровень объектов предметной области" и "Уровень модели предметной области". О которых говорится в [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)